# Python connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connect

Tags: python

try to crawl but something wrong with the host

```py
import psycopg2
import geopandas as gpd
with psycopg2.connect(database="osm_data_science_db",user="postgres",
                      password='password',host='localhost') as connection:
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrama.from_postgis("""SELECT*FROM osm_amenities_areas""", connection, geom_col='geom')
gdf[['osm_id','state','geom','post']].head()`
```